# Take any $n\times k$ matrix $C$ with $r\left(C\right)=k$. $M_{C}=I-C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, transpose

Take any $n\times k$ matrix $C$ with $r\left(C\right)=k$. The rank
condition implies $\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}$ exists. Define $M_{C}=I-C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T}$
1. For any $C$, how can I show that $M_{C}$ is symmetric and idempotent. What is
$r\left(M_{C}\right)$?
2. What is $M_{C}C$? Is there any intuition behind this?
3. Let $A$ be an $n\times k_{A}$ matrix with $r\left(A\right)=k_{A}$.
Similarly, let $B$ be an $n\times k_{B}$ with $r\left(B\right)=k_{B}$.
Further, suppose $r\left(\left[A,B\right]\right)=k_{1}+k_{2}$. Do $\left(A^{T}M_{B}A\right)^{-1}$ and $\left(B^{T}M_{A}B\right)^{-1}$
exist? 
4. Prove that $\left[M_{M_{A}B}\right]A=A$. Is there any intuition behind this?

Comment: Hints for the first two:
 
1. Symmetric means $M_C=M_C^T$. The transpose commutes with taking the inverse (so $((C^TC)^{-1})^T=((C^TC)^T)^{-1})$. Idempotent means $M_CM_C=M_C$. Just do the transpose and multiplication to prove these. Some [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) of matrix rank might help you find $r(M_C)$.
2. Again, to find $M_CC$ just do the multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is idempotent, just follow the definition and you get it:
$$
\begin{align}
M_{C}^2&=(I-C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T})(I-C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T})\\
&=I-C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T} - C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T}+C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T}C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T}\\
&=I-C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T} - C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T}+C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T}=M_{C}
\end{align}$$

and symmetric
$$\begin{align}
M_{C}^T&=
(I-C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T})^T\\
&=I-(C\left(C^{T}C\right)^{-1}C^{T})^T\\
=&I-
(C^{T})^T \left((C^{T}C\right)^{-1})^TC^T\\
=&I-
C \left((C^{T}C\right)^T)^{-1}C^T=M_{C}
\end{align}$$